# how to change legends depending on the value in the database php?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I have a code that check attendance within a certain day on each student enrolled on the class, i want to change the legends depending on the remarks depending on the values on the column at_remark

Here's my code

```
$lastId = "";  //var to check the new students
$daysTDs = ""; // a string holding the TDs of the student e.g '<td>1<td><td><td><td>3<td>....'
$attendees = []; //array to hold the days 
$currentdays = intval(date("t"));

//start query result loop
while($sql_e_res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_e)){
if($sql_e_res['s_usn']!=$lastId){//if new student
    $i = 0;
    //new student ? then build the $daysTDs string from $attendees attay for the previous student
    while ($i++ < $currentdays){ //fot the first student it will be empty and will not get echoed
        if(in_array($i, $attendees)){$daysTDs .= "<td>$i</td>";}
        else{$daysTDs .= "<td></td>";}
    }
    if($lastId!=""){
        echo $daysTDs;//if not first student append the $daysTDs
        echo'</tr>'; //if not first student, then close the row </tr>       
    }
    $attendees = []; // flush the array for the next student
    $daysTDs=""; // empty the TDs string for the next student
    echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$sql_e_res['s_usn'].'</td>
    <td>'.$sql_e_res['s_name'].'</td>';
}
$lastId=$sql_e_res['s_usn'];

$dt = ''.$sql_e_res['at_date'].'';
$dt = strtotime(str_replace(',', '', $dt));
$d = date('j',$dt);
$attendees[]=$d; //push that day to this student attendees array                                               
}
//after the loop is ended finish the last student row
$i=0;
while ($i++ < $currentdays){
   if(in_array($i, $attendees)){$daysTDs .= "<td>$i</td>";}
   else{$daysTDs .= "<td></td>";}
}
echo $daysTDs;
echo'</tr>';
```

Currently i tried if else loop on changing legends like P=0,E=2,U=3, but i cant get it to work

[Here's what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emvvW.jpg)

Comment: You won't get "P" with this code as picture suggest. Use proper variable, column names - it's "the code" itself, no need to encrypt it more. How do you group more names in one table cell while there's only one in table you've shown? Maybe query helpful by any chance?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_attendees order by s_usn asc, at_date asc

Comment: nevermind i already solved it